# Is there any way to know the size of the pure color area of ​a color stop in a gradient?

Tags: html, css

The blue color is cut to the sides and the intermediate part is the part in which the blue color is pure.

Is there no way to know a certain science of what size that area of ​​pure color will be?

As I see the stop is a position that is given to the color but does not say much about how large this area of ​​pure color will be

My interpretation was that the value of the stop was the position in which the color ceased to be pure and began to degrade to the other color.

but that only works if there are only two colors in the gradient

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( black 20%, blue 25%, pink 30%);
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Comment: mathematically it should be almost 0 because you will have a transition between 20% and 25% from black to blue so you will reach blue only at 25% then another transition after. You can have pure color if you define a range between two values

Comment: by the way you have a pure color of black which is 20% of the height and pure pink which is 70% because your gradient is equivalent to `linear-gradient(black 0%, black 20%, blue 25%, pink 30%, pink 100%)`

Comment: Hummm then, the pure color is because navigator is trying to fill the remaining space in the element?

Comment: not exactly, it's how gradient is defined. If you ommit the 0% and 100%, they will be defined automatically then based on that you can conclude what are the pure colors. As I said, it happens only when you have a range of the same color and it's the case in your example with black and pink but not blue.